# How to add search filter option like this image in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add a filter option button without adding a search bar.

**ScreenShot**

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Please be clear with proper explanation.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before and also read [minimal reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
InkWell(
         onTap: () => 
         child: const Icon(
         Icons.tune,
         color: Colors.grey,
           ),
         ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `IconButton` like below

```
IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.tune),
      onPressed: () {},
)
```